# Crash fails to resolve symbol "init_level4_pgt"

Tags: kernel

I am trying following command to analyze crash dump with crash tool **(7.1.4-1ubuntu4.2)**.

```
sudo crash /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.13.16 /var/crash/201804101516/vmcore.201804101516
```

But it fails to with error: crash: cannot resolve "`init_level4_pgt`"

```
crash 7.1.4
Copyright (C) 2002-2015  Red Hat, Inc.
Copyright (C) 2004, 2005, 2006, 2010  IBM Corporation
Copyright (C) 1999-2006  Hewlett-Packard Co
Copyright (C) 2005, 2006, 2011, 2012  Fujitsu Limited
Copyright (C) 2006, 2007  VA Linux Systems Japan K.K.
Copyright (C) 2005, 2011  NEC Corporation
Copyright (C) 1999, 2002, 2007  Silicon Graphics, Inc.
Copyright (C) 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002  Mission Critical Linux, Inc.
This program is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License,
and you are welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under
certain conditions.  Enter "help copying" to see the conditions.
This program has absolutely no warranty.  Enter "help warranty" for details.

GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"...

WARNING: kernel relocated [756MB]: patching 95288 gdb minimal_symbol values


crash: cannot resolve "init_level4_pgt"
```

What could be the possible cause?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the bug is fixed in newer version of crash (crash 7.2.1).